# Vue axios 404 err

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

I have a problem when making an axios request, it returns a 404 error, the file path is fine since it is in the same directory and I do not understand why it returns that error,

I am using vue-cli, and I run the server with npm run serve instead of express.

**Register.vue**

```
 var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("nombre", nombre);
  formData.append("mail", mail);
  formData.append("pass", pass);

  axios
    .post("./auth_register.php", formData)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

**auth_register.php**

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && $_POST['mail'] && $_POST['pass']) {
     return json_encode("received");                                                         
   } else {
     return null;
   }
```

I don't know why this happens

I am new to vue do not be angry

Comment: _"the file path is fine since it is in the same directory"_ - If you have a router/routes, then it might not matter if the file is in the same folder or not. It's always best to write the paths relative from the document root (ex: `/path/to/auth_register.php`) instead of using `./`. When using things like `./`, the path will be relative from the URL, so if the current URL is: `/foo/bar`, then it will look for the file in `/foo/bar/auth_register.php`. Where is the file located in relation to the document root/public folder?

Comment: file is in : 

 - src (root)
    - auth 
         - auth_register.php

Comment: If `src` is your document root (the folder that you've configured your web server to use as document root), then the path should be `/auth/auth_register.php`.

Comment: nope, i try this path and throw same error 404 @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path; Worked for me!  after long searching
example ->  http://localhost:8080/api/authentication/login.php

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).